# Select a file under two subfolders and save it in the subfolders

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I want to select a file under two subfolders and save it in the subfolders I have set in the ModelBuilder in ArcGIS.

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you put up a picture of the model you have?  Also, could you clarify what you want to do?  Do you have a file at Folder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\FILE and want to move it to Subfolder1, or are you looking to move it to a completely different folder or subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to only do this once, you can just drag-and-drop using ArcCatalog.  If it's something you'll be doing a lot and need the model for, you should be able to get by with [Copying](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy.htm) the shapefile from the starting location to the destination.  Then set the resulting file as a prerequisite to [Delete](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/delete.htm) the original.  Set the destination folder as a parameter and you've got yourself a working model.  You can set the initial file as a parameter, too, to give yourself more flexibility.